# Solve the exponential

Tags: exponential-function

If $$ A =
        \begin{bmatrix}
        3 & 4 \\
        4 & -3  
        \end{bmatrix}$$

Can someone find $\mathbf e^A$ ?

Edit 1:- I got this question in my fucntional analysis paper ! How is it even related to functional analysis ? Can somebody explain ?

Comment: See [here](http://matriisi.ee.tut.fi/~piche/ode/expm2/).

Comment: Not a duplicate as far as I can see -- this doesn't satisfy $A^k=I$.

Answer (score 1):

$A$ is diagonalizable ! $A$ has the eigenvalues $ \pm 5$. Let $D:=\begin{bmatrix}
        5 & 0 & \\
        0 & -5 & 
        \end{bmatrix}$.

It is your turn to find an invertible matrix $P$ such that

$A=P^{-1}DP$.

Then $e^A=P^{-1}e^DP$.

$e^D$ is easy to compute.